# Vue remove invalid input message

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

When an input field requires more info, the browser shows a message in a bubble about why the input is invalid. I would like to prevent the default for this in vue but I'm not sure how. Below is how I would do it in JavaScript but in Vue, there may be a way to do `@invalid` like how I know you can do `@submit` on a form as an eventListener. I'm also wondering if extra prevention is needed to prevent this in ios or android.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector( "input" ).addEventListener( "invalid",
 function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
  });
```

https://codepen.io/albert-anthony4962/pen/BajORVZ

Comment: Hi albert_anthony6! Could you put up a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) showing the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Yes. The first input is what I seek. To disable the message. The second input shows the default message. https://codepen.io/albert-anthony4962/pen/BajORVZ

Comment: Thanks for adding that codepen! Unfortunately, I don't think it really shows the problem  It doesn't seem like Vue is being included on the page, and I don't see any validation messages being displayed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely disable validation, you can add `novalidate="true"` to your `form` element.

I suspect that you might only want to do that on the initial page load. If so, could you update your section and hopefully and add an example? I can update my answer after that

Comment: I only want to disable the message, novalidate will overwrite the required attribute which i don't want. Only the message should be disabled please

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I have (idea from Vuetify) is pretty easy:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isFormValid: null,
    form: {
      input_1: {
        text: null,
        rules: ['required', 'min3'],
        validateText: null
      },
      input_2: {
        text: null,
        rules: ['required'],
        validateText: null
      }
    },
    rules: {
      required: v => !!v && !![...v].length || 'This field is required.',
      min3: v => !!v && !!([...v].length > 2) || 'This field must be at least 3 characters long.'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validateForm() {
      const validated = []
      for (let key in this.form) {
        const v = this.form[key].rules.map(e => {
          return this.rules[e](this.form[key].text)
        })
        if (v.some(e => e !== true)) {
          this.form[key].validateText = v.filter(e => e !== true)[0]
          validated.push(false)
        } else {
          this.form[key].validateText = "This field is valid."
          validated.push(true)
        }
      }
      return validated.every(e => e === true)
    },
    submitForm() {
      if (this.validateForm()) {
        // submit logic
        this.isFormValid = "Yes, it's valid."
      } else {
        // not valid logic:
        this.isFormValid = "No, it's not valid."
      }
    },
    resetValidation() {
      const form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form))
      for (let key in form) {
        form[key].validateText = null
      }
      this.isFormValid = null
      this.form = form
    },
    resetForm() {
      const form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form))
      for (let key in form) {
        form[key].validateText = null
        form[key].text = null
      }
      this.isFormValid = null
      this.form = form
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form ref="formRef">
    <label for="input_1">
      Input 1: 
      <input
        id="input_1"
        type="text"
        v-model="form.input_1.text"
      />
    </label>
    <div>This field will validate if NOT EMPTY AND HAS AT LEAST 3 CHARS</div>
    <div>{{ form.input_1.validateText || '&nbsp;' }}</div>
    <br />
    <label for="input_2">
      Input 2: 
      <input
        id="input_2"
        type="text"
        v-model="form.input_2.text"
      />
    </label>
    <div>This field will validate if NOT EMPTY</div>
    <div>{{ form.input_2.validateText || '&nbsp;' }}</div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" @click.prevent="submitForm">
      SUBMIT
    </button>
    <div>Is the form valid? {{ isFormValid }}</div>
  </form>
  <button @click="resetValidation">RESET VALIDATION</button><br />
  <button @click="resetForm">RESET FORM</button>
</div>
```

This way you don't have to put up with the HTML5 "bubbles", but can still validate your form - in any way you need. You can compose any validation scheme you want by using functions that go over your input text. You could even come up with `regexp` validation, pattern validation (like phone numbers), etc. It's not the greatest solution, but quite "pluggable".

This is also supposed to be cross-platform (if you use **Vue**).